# Angular Service class properties are undefined when trying to set something to them inside of a function

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have a registration page with a form. The user clicks a register button which goes to a register function in the component. The register function in the component makes 2 calls: authService.register and then authService.verifyUser.

Register is working fine. However, in verifyUser I keep getting an error that my class properties (this.loggedInUser and this.userLoggedIn) are undefined when trying to set something to them. It seems like something is messed up with the scope, but why wouldn't I be able to set class properties at any time from any function?

```
export class AuthService {
  userLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  loggedInUser: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  register(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert(`${error.message} Please Try Again!`);
      });
  }

  verifyUser() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      this.loggedInUser = user.email;
      this.userLoggedIn = true;
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
    }
  });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
 var me = this;
 firebase.auth()....{
 me.loggedIn....
 }
```

Comment: this worked, will mark as accepted as soon as it lets me. Is this a common typescript thing? Is it because inside of a promise/observable you can't access this?

Comment: yes, value of this is different inside the success function.

Comment: @BlakeRivell I bet SO lets you accept this as the answer now. ;^)